# Android Content Provider Update not working

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, android-contentprovider

I have a code which updates a column called status but the update is not taking place.

Here's how I call the provider:

```html
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(1);
  values.put(ChatDataProvider.COL_STATUS, 0);
  getContentResolver().update(Uri.withAppendedPath(ChatDataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, "lastcliq/" + userIdOther.toString()), values, null, null);
```

And here's my update override:

```html
 @Override
 public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  int count = 0;
  switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
  case MESSAGES_LAST_MSG_BY_ID:
   count = db.update(TABLE_MESSAGES, values, COL_USER_ID_TO + " = ?", new String[]{uri.getLastPathSegment()}); 
   break; 
  default:
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported URI: " + uri);   
  }
  getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
  return count;
 }
```

The weird thing is "db.update" returns a count of 2 which is correct but the values of COL_STATUS is not set to 0 as when I query again, the same rows still have status=1.

All other methods in my Content Provider perform as expected.

Comment: Have you looked at what is actually in the database? Are you sure that when you query again, that you are getting and using the new `Cursor` with the new results?